# QT 5.6: Segmentation violation in second call to QGraphicsScene::addItem()

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

I keep getting a segmentation violation in my second call to QGraphicsScene::addItem().

The following code works the first time, but after terminating/reloading QDialog, QApplication, etc. (called in a DLL), code fails consistently on second use with the same image!?!

Makes me wonder if the destructors terminated cleanly, or if I might need to reinitialize QApplication differently.

Suggestions, please? Here is my code in question...

```
    PBITMAPINFOHEADER pDIBInfoHeader = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)m_pImage;
    QGraphicsScene *pgs = new QGraphicsScene();
    pgs->setSceneRect(0.0, 0.0, 70.0, 80.0);
    QSize qs(70, 80);

    int width = pDIBInfoHeader->biWidth;
    int height = pDIBInfoHeader->biHeight;

    uchar *pBits = (uchar *)m_pImage + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    QImage *pqi = new QImage((uchar *)pBits, width, height, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
    QImage qiFlip = pqi->mirrored(false, true);         //flip image vertically
    delete pqi;

    QPixmap *ppm = new QPixmap;
    if (!ppm->convertFromImage(qiFlip.scaled(qs, Qt::KeepAspectRatio), Qt::NoFormatConversion))
        cdbg << "ppm->convertFromImage false" << endl;

    // DOES QGRAPHICSPIXMAPITEM TAKE OWNERSHIP OF QPIXMAP?
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(*ppm, 0);    

    delete ppm;

    pgs->addItem(item);  // <<< SIGSEGV
    ui->grXray->setScene(pgs);
```

Notes: pgs is the only item in the scene. The scene is not active.

I rebuilt QT with debug options for Windows MSVC 2015, and can see lots of detail, but the intricacies of C++ templates, QVariant and QMetaType escape me.  Where should I look for corruption?

Here is call stack of SIGSEGV:

```
QMetaType::construct(void * where, const void * copy) Line 2153 C++
`anonymous namespace'::customConstruct(QVariant::Private * d, const void * copy) Line 1020 C++
QVariant::QVariant(const QVariant & p) Line 1372 C++
QGraphicsItem::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsI temChange change, const QVariant & value) Line 7447 C++
QGraphicsScene::addItem(QGraphicsItem * item) Line 2496 C++
```

QT code snippets:

```
inline void *QMetaType::construct(void *where, const void *copy) const
{
if (Q_UNLIKELY(isExtended(ConstructEx)))
return constructExtended(where, copy);
return m_constructor(where, copy);                 //<<<<<<<<
}


QVariant::QVariant(const QVariant &p)
: d(p.d)
{
if (d.is_shared) {
d.data.shared->ref.ref();
} else if (p.d.type > Char) {
handlerManager[d.type]->construct(&d, p.constData());   //<<<<<<
d.is_null = p.d.is_null;
}
}


void QGraphicsScene::addItem(QGraphicsItem *item)
...
// Notify the item that its scene is changing, and allow the item to
// react.
const QVariant newSceneVariant(item->itemChange(QGraphicsItem::ItemSceneChange,
QVariant::fromValue<QGraphicsScene *>(this)));  // <<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Do you really need to destroy your QApplication object and recreate it?  Most Qt programs keep a single QApplication object around for the duration of the process (e.g. declared as a stack object near the top of main(), or similar); I suspect that destroying and recreating the QApplication object is something the Qt developers didn't anticipate, so there may be a bug there that they aren't aware of.

Comment: Hmm,  our application framework deletes QApplication on termination.   I tried to skip that delete, and still got SIGSEGV deep in QCoreApplication::postEvent();

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `pqi` nor `ppm` to be constructed on the heap. <strike>Also you are destroying ppm while it's still in use.</strike>

A cleaner version of your code would be:

```
QImage image((uchar *)pBits, width, height, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
QImage flippedImage = image.mirrored(false, true); //flip image vertically
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(flippedImage.scaled(qs, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));    
pgs->addPixmap(pixmap);
```

The code can even be made shorter but it will start to be less readable.

Comment: AFAICT the "you are destroying ppm while it's still in use" is not true.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No you didn't, that phrase was meant to be deleted after I realized I misread the code sample. QPixmap being an implicitly shared class, deleting it in that order is OK since it should only decrement the reference counter.